# Holes in walls above ten tefach

Tags: talmud-bavli, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot, maseches-shabbos

[The *Bavli*, *Shabas* 7 *amud* 2](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=137), has a discussion about holes in walls, where things might land if thrown. Holes on the *r'shus-hayachid*-facing side of a wall are deemed *r'shus hayachid*, so tossing something into one from within the *r'shus hayachid* is permissible. The question arises, though, what holes on a *r'shus-harabim*-facing side of a wall are considered: *r'shus harabim* or not.

The next four paragraphs (five including this one) provide detail about the *g'mara* and basis for my question: skip down to the horizontal rule if you're familiar with the *g'mara* and *Rashi* or simply wish to get to the gist of my question.

*Rashi* (ד״ה לאו כרשות הרבים דמו) says that in the second alternative — that such holes are not *r'shus harabim* — they'd be considered a separate *r'shus*: thus (he continues), if they are four *tefach* square they're a *karm'lis* and otherwise they're a *m'kom p'tur*. Note that a four-*tefach*-square area would normally be a *karm'lis* only less than ten *tefach* off the ground: more than ten *tefach* off the ground, such an area would normally be a *r'shua hayachid*. This is the first indication (to me) that these holes in walls under halachic discussion may be *only* those less than ten *tefach* off the ground.

Let's continue — excusing, if you please, my quasi-stream-of-consciousness post.

The *g'mara* goes on to cite a *mishna* that says if you throw something at a wall four *amos* away, more ten *tefach* off the ground, you're exempt; but lower than that, you're liable as if the thrown object had landed on the ground. *Rabi Yochanan*'s interpretation of this is given: that the thrown object stuck to the wall. That *Rabi Yochanan* didn't offer the simpler explanation, that the object landed in a hole in the wall, indicates, the *g'mara* says, that had it landed in such a hole, lower than ten *tefach*, the thrower would be exempt — proof that holes in the wall are not considered *r'shus harabim*. The *g'mara* counters that the wall in question has no holes, and that that's the reason *Rabi Yochanan* didn't say that the object landed in a hole in the wall. How do we know it has no holes? Well, from the first case of the *mishna*: that the object reached the wall above ten *tefach*. If the wall had holes and the thrown object landed in one, the thrower would be liable, even above ten *tefach*!

Now, wait a second. (This is me speaking now, not the *g'mara*.) *Why* would the thrower be liable then? I'd think that, since the hole is considered *r'shus harabim* (the hypothesis of this whole series of arguments in the *g'mara*), he'd be liable for throwing something four *amos* in a *r'shus harabim*. Not so, says *Rashi*: he'd be liable because "הא ה״ל מרה״ר לרה״י דהוה ליה גבוה י׳ ורשות לעצמו‎ / it's [a throw] from *r'shus harabim* to *r'shus hayachid*, for [the hole] is ten *tefach* off the ground and its own *r'shus*". This explanation is my second indication that the halachic discussion of whether holes in walls are considered *r'shus harabim* applies *only* to those less than ten *tefach* off the ground — and this one's a strong indication in my opinion. Moreover, *Rashi*'s explanation is necessitated by the next step in the *g'mara*, which also indicates as much — but I'll stop here.

---

So *Rashi* and even the *g'mara* seem to indicate that the holes in walls that may be considered *r'shus harabim* are only those that are less than ten *tefach* off the ground.

1. Is this explicit anywhere? I inferred it from the argument of the *g'mara* and the wording of *Rashi*, but it seems like an important point to omit. (Moreover, maybe I'm wrong, and the holes in walls that may be considered *r'shus harabim* are even those more than ten *tefach* up. If so, that'd make a good answer to this subquestion (and then ignore my second subquestion).)
2. Does this apply only to the *r'shus-harabim* side, or are holes on the *r'shus-hayachid* side of a wall, also, considered *r'shus hayachid* only up to ten *tefach* off the ground? I suspect (strongly) that the *r'shus-hayachid* side may be different, since, generally, *r'shus-harabim* airspace is not considered *r'shus harabim* higher than ten *tefach*, which is not true of *r'shus hayachid*; but just as I have no explicit source to say the *r'shus-harabim*-side holes in walls are (possibly) *r'shus harabim* only up to ten *tefach*, so do I have no explicit source to say the *r'shus-hayachid*-side holes in walls are *r'shus hayachid* even higher than ten *tefach*.

Comment: If the holes start higher than 10 tefachim up, then they aren't attache to a reshus harabbim to begin with! how would they possibly be consider RH"R if they aren't connected to one and can't constitute one on their own? ... Oop, it seems @HaLeiVi makes the same point...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky, see my comment on his answer.

Comment: granted that he's not providing an explicit source, what constitutes 1) explication and 2) a "valid" source for your answer?

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky, I was thinking the _g'mara_ might say somewhere that a hole in a wall above ten _tefach_ is not _r'shus harabim_ or that the discussion I refer to is only about holes within ten _tefach_ of the ground, or that _Rashi_ might, or that some other commentary on the _g'mara_ might -- rather than my having to infer it the way I did.

Answer (score -1):

The only case ever of Reshus Harabim above 10 Tephachim is on the shoulders, like the B'nei Levi. The Gemara is discussing if the the hole being open to the area renders it as a part of the domain it is open to. We know without any doubt that Reshus Harabim is only up to ten Tephachim. Therefore, there never was any question that the hole being discussed here (facing Reshus Harabim) is within the ten Tephachim.

As for Reshus Hayachis, it is as you said, Reshus Hayachid Oleh Ad Harakiah, it goes all the way up.

Comment: I mention in the question already that "generally, _r'shus-harabim_ airspace is not considered _r'shus harabim_ higher than ten _tefach_, which is not true of _r'shus hayachid_", so this answer doesn't really add much to what I knew already. Specifically, my question was whether that same rule applied to holes in walls specifically is "explicit anywhere", and this doesn't supply such citation.

Comment: @msh210 Well, nobody is walking in that hole. The only factor would be if the Rabim can use it for package shifting. But that already has a set height of nine Tephachim.

Answer (score -2):

One ought to just have fixed the hole in the wall in the first place, which also helps you avoid the issue of whether you have to search it for *chametz* come Passover and worry whether your gentile neighbors who share the wall will think you're casting spells and come harm you, or fear that you might get stung by a scorpion. (Pesachim P1 8a / Steinsaltz v6 p39). Also, your mother is hollering at you for throwing things at the wall.

Glibness aside. :) As a contributing note Pesachim discusses holes in walls in the context of searching for chametz, and determining which holes you are required to search and not required to search. It hints at the same issue you are investigating, which is the boundary between usefulness/accessibility and that which is inconvenient or dangerous enough that you are not liable for it.

> The gemara answers: The apparent contradiction between the first ruling with regard to holes and the second ruling with regard to holes is not difficult. This baraita, which rules that one need not search them, is referring to upper and lower holes, which are difficult to use. And that baraita, which rules that one is required to search them, is referring to intermediate holes, whose use is convenient. (Steinsaltz Bavli Pesachim PI d8a / v6 p38)